# How to write the setter for a property which is an array of objects and to be populated by the view, in Angular 2 (ts)

Tags: angular, typescript, setter, angular-ngmodel

Property:

```
private _secretQuestions: {question: number, answer: string}[];
```

I have three select boxes(question) in my html and for each select box, there is an input(answer) box. I want to bind the selected and input values to the property _secretQuestions. 
As there are only three questions, I thought of initializing the array like this:

```
private _secretQuestions = [{question: 0, answer: ""}, {question: 0, answer: ""}, {question: 0, answer: ""}];
```

But I am just unable to write the setter for this property:

```
set secretQuestions(value: Array<{question: number, answer: string}>) {
    // what code here?
}
```

In my html,

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="regModel.secretQuestions">
... </select>
```

calls the setter, but if it was somehow possible to call the setter like:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="regModel.secretQuestions[0].question">
```

I think I could have got my problem solved.

Can you please suggest the right approach for this?

---

**EDIT**

The property _securityQuestions belongs to a Provider, and is injected into the component. The provider has to have the property as private.

Answer (score 0):

Angular's `NgModel` directive does not require a setter. You bind to the property directly e.g:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="regModel.secretQuestions[0].question">`
```

That gives you two-way binding, if you want to handle a change in the value you can use something like:

```
<select [ngModel]="regModel.secretQuestions[0].question"
        (ngModelChange)="updateQuestion($event)">
```

Angular official guide on forms has more info https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html in particular [https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html#!#inside-*-ngmodel-*](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html#!#inside-_-ngmodel-_)

Comment: I have edited the question, the property belongs to a provider which has it private, so actually need a setter for this purpose. So ngModel doesn't work this way. I think I will have to pass even the index in the ngChange trigger now.

Comment: If keep your provider private then yes you will have to pass the index to the `updateQuestion` method. Why don't you keep the state of the form in the component or don't use a provider with private properties?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the "2-way-binding" like

```
<select class="form-control" [ngModel]="regModel.secretQuestions" 
    (ngModelChange)="secretQuestion = regModel.secretQuestions[0].question">
```